# trying to create auto scaling group under configuring scaling policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMDqz.png)

trying to create auto scaling group under configuring scaling policies, Increase Group Size, take action is not showing the instances under drop down but it is showing only "capacity units" and "percent of groups"

what is percent of groups and capacity units please explain

Comment: Please review the help documentation for StackOverflow. Specifically on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 

I also suggest reading the documentation for AWS as this is thoroughly covered: https://docs.aws.amazon.com

Answer (score 0):

AutoScaling just added the ability to give different instance types different weights (Capacity units), so the 'capacity units' option replaced the 'instances' option.  If you're not using this new option, then each instance is 1 capacity unit.

So you can either choose to have the scaling policy add more capacity units (formerly instances), or increase the current desired based by a percent (example: If the current desired is 10, and the scaling policy is set to add 20%, it would go up to 12).

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-ec2-auto-scaling-supports-instance-weighting/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html